# Grails url mapping layout not loaded

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I edited UrlMappings.groovy to map my root "/" directory to a special view.

What I did was

```
"/"(controller: 'myController', action: 'index')
```

The problem is that the layout in this index view isn't loaded. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: myController have index action?

Comment: Yeah. The weird thing is the full path loads the layout /myView/index. The layout can't be injected into the page when I use this mapping... The page is loaded without the layout..

Comment: How your `index` method looks like?

Comment: just passing list of domain objects to the view

Comment: did you get any errors?. Like 404

Comment: Show you `index` method. Tell us where your layout resides. etc..

Comment: Damn. Yeah didn't notice the picture is missing which is under ../images/myLogo.png. I have this image under web-app/images/myImage.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"/"(controller:'main', action:'index')
```

and

```
def index(){}
```

with layout in

```
../grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp
```

works for me.

**[edited]**

Move your image under here, like

```
../grails-app/assets/images/my-image.png
```

then, use

```
<g:img dir="images" file="my-image.png"/>
```

in your page.

Comment: Hello brother. The problem is the image is under localhost:8080/myApp/images/myImage.png now when I do the url mapping the console say can't find the picture under  
http://localhost:8080/images/myImage.png

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood mapping with redirect. I just wanted open the default page when the server starts.

Comment: Right. So, you need to move it to the suggested place. Any problems?

Comment: Nope, it's just a grails way of packaging things. You can inspect the `build` (`.war`), the `build` doesn't have that `asset` directory, and you will notice that things are in there proper places.

Comment: ../grails-app/images/myImage.png works... The problem is that g.createLink is messed up then... I guess I should create a controller which just redirects... Yes No?

Comment: No, it's `grails-app/assets/images/..` not `grails-app/images/..`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125103/discussion-between-adeel-ansari-and-moonstar).

Comment: Thanks. Accepted solution. I used put <img src="${assetPath(src: 'myPicture.jpg')}" /> and it worked...

Comment: Try this, `<g:img dir="images" file="myImage.png"/>`, instead.

Comment: Try This : <img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'myImage.png')}" title="Image" border="0"/> , It's automatically create image resource url.